# Yii x-editable datetpick display error when using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, yii, datatable

I am using PHP Yii framework and tried to make a table column(with "date" type value) editable by [Yii X-editable](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/).

Everything works fine,just as https://i.stack.imgur.com/A21se.jpg

But,when I started to make the table more friendly by [Jquery datatable](https://datatables.net).The datepicker appeared strange.http://imgur.com/G6X9vHQ

Could someone give me hint?Thanks.

Comment: are there any js errors in your firebug/console ?